# How to get the hidden input's value with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In python3 I want to extract information from a page using requests and beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/listarPartes.asp?termo=AECIO%20NEVES%20DA%20CUNHA"

try:
    res = requests.get(link)
except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
    print(str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("Exceção")

html = res.content.decode('utf-8') 

soup =  BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

pag = soup.find('div', {'id': 'total'})

print(pag)
```

In this case the information is in an HTML snippet like this:

```
<div id="total" style="display: inline-block"><input type="hidden" name="totalProc" id="totalProc" value="35">35</div>
```

What I want to access is value, in this case 35. Capture number "35"

That's why I used "pag = soup.find('div', {'id': 'total'})". To slowly isolate just the number 35

But the content returned was just: `<div id="total" style="display: inline-block"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"/></div>`

Please does anyone know how to capture value content only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is dynamically pulled from another XHR call you can find in the network tab

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/totalProcessosPartes.asp?termo=AECIO%20NEVES%20DA%20CUNHA&total=0')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#totalProc')['value'])
```

With regex

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/totalProcessosPartes.asp?termo=AECIO%20NEVES%20DA%20CUNHA&total=0')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(re.search('value=(\d+)',r.text).groups(0)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a standard solution, but I personally like using regexes to isolate values from my BeautifulSoup results since they can help capture any kind of pattern. For example, in your case, if you decide to use regex your code could look like:

```
soup =  str(BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml"))

import regex
pag = regex.findall(r'(?<=value=")\d+', soup)

print(pag[0])
```

You can verify that the regex returns the content in value [here](https://regex101.com/r/3JKfTv/1).

Comment: I don't think the problem is only the syntax, but actually the web page too: I believe it's still loading the information when when BeautifulSoup try to parse it. I'm actually not sure if bf and requests are powerful enough for this kind of task. In cases like this I'd just use selenium to bypass it.

Comment: Thanks @Anshul Rai I'm sorry I don't know the regex in depth. In this case it returns only the number "3". Is it capturing the content of other "value" in HTML?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves yes, it is capturing the content of all value tags since I used `findall`.  You can still access each individual match by incrementing the index in `print(pag[i])`. I had made this particular regex *specifically* for the html snippet that you had shared, so I guess you would need a more general one for your complete html code if you decide to use regexes here.

Comment: I'm telling you, it's capturing this thing here:
 `<input type="hidden" value="3" id="abaSelecionada" />`. 
As I said, the information you're loking for has not been loaded yet into the page, as that is done through an ajax call.

Comment: @AnshulRai But I think this is not the case with several "value =". Because print(pag) returns only 3

Comment: Thanks @MicheleBastione So in Python this can't be done? Or rather, just with selenium?

Comment: I don't know if it can be done with BeautifulSoup, but I've always used selenium and it always worked fine. Let me write a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

As I was explaining in the comments, browser automation can be a very quick solution to this issue. The first thing thing you should do is installing Google Chrome on your computer if you haven't got it already. To be fair it could work with any browser, but then I wouldn't be sure on how to set up the code properly, as I have never done it before. Secondly, you must download a tool called "chrome webdriver". You can find it [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/). Once downloaded, extract the file and put it in the same directory of your python script, which should be the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time

ch = Options()
ch.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
ch.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
ch.add_argument("--headless")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = ch)
page = browser.get("https://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/listarPartes.asp?termo=AECIO%20NEVES%20DA%20CUNHA")
time.sleep(1)
pag = browser.find_element_by_id('totalProc')

print(pag.get_attribute('value'))
browser.quit()
```

Before executing it, don't forget to do `pip install selenium` in your terminal in order to install the actual selenium module.
The script takes about 10-20 seconds to run, but it should work perfectly fine.
Let me know if you have any trouble with it, but you definitely shouldn't.